# Rails server on Windows keeps trying to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed Ruby 2.6.4 and Rails 6.0 on Windows. I created a new project with "rails new blog". When it finished I entered the blog folder and ran "rails s" and the server tries to start and keeps trying without showing any errors, but it never starts:

[image]

I tried to start the server on another port but the same thing happens.

I check the log folder to see if it tells me anything, but the development.log file is empty.

Anyone know what might be happening?

The exact versions of Ruby and Rails are:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried localhost:3000 on the browser?

Comment: Yes, and it shows "Can not connect".

Answer (score 0):

Windows is not a good solution for Ruby and Ruby on Rails. Please, try install Ubuntu and enjoy Ruby programming :)

If you still want to use Windows - try to install Rails 5.2.3, maybe it will help.